# Disable row selection for a few rows only in a p:dataTable

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I would like to know if there is a way of disabling the radio-based row selection for a given set of rows in Primefaces, based on a bean property.

Example:

```html
<p:dataTable var="foo" value="#{bean.foos}" selection="#{bean.selectedFoo}">`
    <p:column selectionMode="single" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{foo.bar}" />
    </p:column>
<p:dataTable>
```

In this case, imagine I would like to disable the rows where `foo.bar == 1,5,10`, by disabling the rows I mean disable the radio button associated with the row.

I couldn't figure out a way of accomplish that... any ideas? Even a css + javascript hack solution would be acceptable.

Comment: Add the *disabled* attribute to the relevant radio buttons.

Comment: @Redder you should update the marked solution to the second answer the new PF disabledSelection attribute in PF5.0+

Comment: @Melloware Thanks for pointing that!

Comment: No problem thanks for fixing!

Comment: @Melloware `disabledSelection` is actually there since PF4.0.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Since 4.0 version, Primefaces datatable comes with a `disabledSelection` property.

```
<p:dataTable var="foo" value="#{bean.foos}" selection="#{bean.selectedFoo}" disabledSelection="#{foo.bar == 1}">
    <p:column selectionMode="single" />
    <p:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{foo.bar}" />
    </p:column>
<p:dataTable>
```

Then, when `foo.bar == 1` is true, checkbox will be disabled.

Comment: The original question asked specifically for a way to disable a 'given set of rows' rather than 'all' rows, which is what this feature provides.

Comment: It does not disable all rows, only those which match with the condition. Here, it disables only the rows where the attribute "bar" is equals to 1.

Comment: what if we want to compare with string value?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue where I wanted to disable only certain rows from selection (single or multiple) based on a bean property.  The short answer for me was to just hide the radio/checkbox on that row so it could not be selected.  My needs required me to be able to process additional selections at run-time.  This meant that I had to be sure the row(s) were un-selected physically before any further selections were made so they weren't re-processed in subsequent processing, so beware of that condition.

Here's what I did, for others that may stumble upon this question in the future.

1) In the p:datatable I added the rowStyleClass attribute, and based on the bean criteria, provided a class, such as: 'is-selectable' or 'not-selectable'.

```
rowStyleClass="#{myBean.alreadyProcessedList.contains(item) ? 'not-selectable' : 'is-selectable'}"
```

In my run-time process, selected rows were added to this list so they would be made 'not-selectable' once the form was rendered again after processing.  Your initial load should have the non-selectable rows already added to the list, or handle through whatever condition you need in your case.

2) Define CSS to make the .not-selectable hide the radio/checkbox.  Using '!important' was necessary to override the in-line styling.

```
tr.not-selectable  div.ui-radiobutton,
tr.not-selectable  div.ui-chkbox {
    visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  try disabling  with Jquery as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script>
         $(function(){
              $("#myform  input[type = radio]:nth(1)").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
</script>
```

myform:your Form Name
Inplace of nth(1) 
you can mention the row number to be dispbled.

Answer (score -1):

Set the Property ***disabledSelection*** (Disables row selection when true. Overrides
p:column's disabledSelection attr. Example:
var="xxx" disabledSelection="#{xxx.year >
1960}"

Comment: This is already in the accepted answer... No need for an additional one