# How to make Selection Disable/Enable dynamically in DataTable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

How can I make the Primefaces `p:dataTable` selection Enable or Disable or Multiple or Single dynamically based on some condition.

Comment: more information see this blog http://balusc.blogspot.in/2006/06/using-datatables.html

Comment: This could be interesting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395593/disable-row-selection-for-a-few-rows-only-primefaces

Comment: @what'up: That ancient blog is about JSF 1.x `<h:dataTable>`, not about JSF 2.x let alone PrimeFaces. PrimeFaces has already extensive examples in its own showcase site.

Answer (score 0):

There is `disabledSelection` attribute of `p:dataTable` in PrimeFaces 5+. Using this attribute with proper data table update, enable/disable row selection can be reached.