# How to disable row selection of in Primefaces 4.0 with single selection features?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 4.0 in my application. Single row selection feature is implemented for the p:datatable as shown below:

```
     <p:dataTable id="assignmentList" var="assignment"
     value="#{shortageController.allAssignments}"
     rowKey="#{assignment.transportAssignment.id}"
     selection="#{shortageController.selectedAssignment}"
     selectionMode="single" emptyMessage="#{common['no.assignments.found.with.given.criteria']}"
     rowStyleClass="#{assignment.assignmentStyleClass}">
```

I want the selection feature to be disabled when a particular condition is satisfied. How to do that?Is disabledSelection attribute used in primefaces 4.0.Kindly advise.

Comment: When you look into the [corresponding documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/documentation/) you see PF 4 dataTable also provides a disabledSelection attribute.

Comment: @Selaron if there is no duplicate, why not answer it?

Comment: But the 'sort of duplicate' states this attribute is only available for 5.0+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395593/disable-row-selection-for-a-few-rows-only-primefaces

Comment: @Kukeltje it's wrong. It's there since 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable row selection for a few rows only - Primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395593/disable-row-selection-for-a-few-rows-only-primefaces)

Comment: @JasperdeVries I hadn't searched for a duplicate because I considered it more streight forward to take a look into the docs first. This Q lacks on research and own attempt so I did'nt think it's worth keeping/answering for future readers. Now that a dup was found I agree to CV. My first comment was just ment to be the friendly variant of r-t-f-m ;)