# disable row selection on specific row on String comparison in p:datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, el

i am trying to disable the particular row using the below thread. But i am not able to compare a string using the same logic. for the given string.

```
<p:dataTable var="foo" value="#{bean.foos}" selection="#{bean.selectedFoo}" disabledSelection="#{foo.bar == Sample Text}">
<p:column selectionMode="single" />
<p:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{foo.bar}" />
</p:column>
```

The above code is not executing with == for Strings

The error from the console:

I have tried with `disabledSelection="#{foo.bar == Sample Text}"` but it is throwoing error

```
disabledSelection="#{(foo.bar == Sample Text)}" Failed to parse the expression [#{(foo.bar== Sample Text)}]
```

[Original Thread with integer or Long comparision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46426622/1018075)

Comment: I have tried with `disabledSelection="#{foo.bar == Sample Text}"` but it is throwoing error `disabledSelection="#{(foo.bar == Sample Text)}" Failed to parse the expression [#{(foo.bar== Sample Text)}]`

Comment: Use `#{foo.bar == 'Sample Text'}`

Comment: Yes @JasperdeVries it is working. Thanks.