# Primefaces: How to restrict reordering last few rows in a datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using Primefaces 8.0 and have a datatable which allows reordering. I want to reorder all the row, but last 3 rows. How to do that? Please help me, I couldnt find anything that solves my requirement.

```
<p:ajax event="rowReorder" listener="#{bean.onRowReorder}" update=":form"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Idea1)

Is this of any help? My guess is it's not, but i didn't test it.

[Disable row selection for a few rows only in a p:dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395593/disable-row-selection-for-a-few-rows-only-in-a-pdatatable)

Idea2)

Could you make that rows be **first** 3 and say frozenRows=3? Maybe give them different CSS?

Idea3)

Write javascript function and call it onstart in p:ajax. Pass datatable widget as parameter and try in there to determine which row is dragged?

Edit:

Idea4)

See Melloware comment here:
https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2457

Maybe it's possible to override function  PrimeFaces.widget.DataTable.prototype.makeRowsDraggable
so it ignore last 3 rows... could be complicated, not sure

Comment: I will try all these and update here.